# Send props on navigation goBack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Basically I have three screens, the first is a stack navigator:

```
const stackNav = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
            header: null,
        })
    },
    Detail: {
        screen: DetailScreen,
        navigationOptions: (props) => ({
            title: "Detail",
        })
    }
})
```

The second one I have a button to go to the Detail screen:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", {name: l.name, subtitle: l.subtitle})}>
```

The last one is just information, I would like to click a button and execute:
`this.props.navigation.goBack()`, but sending props to the second screen (MainScreen), a setState and a integer id, how can I do that?

--**EDIT WITH PARAMS**--

I have this function in MainScreen:

```
handleOrdem(texto) {
    console.log('texto: '+texto)
    this.setState({
        param: global.ordemAtiva,
        ordemAtiva: !this.state.ordemAtiva
    });
}
//The onPress code:
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", {name: l.name, subtitle: l.subtitle, ordemFunc: () => this.handleOrdem()})}>
```

and this is how I call it in Detail.screen:

```
execBack(param){
    console.log('param: '+param);
    this.props.navigation.state.params.ordemFunc(param);
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
//Button to do it
onPress={() => this.execBack('test')}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a Method in parent screen

```
returnData(){
    PERDROM_EVENT_WITH_RECEIVED_DATA
}
```

Then bind this method `returnData` with navigation code while executing navigation code

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", {name: l.name, subtitle: l.subtitle , returnData: this.returnData.bind(this)})}
```

In child Component call `returnData` method before call of `goBack()`

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData(RETURN_DATA_YOU_WANT);
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

**Handling return data**

Suppose you want two parameters back then add two parms in `returnData()` method

For example we took first param is boolean and second param String

```
 returnData(flag,id){
    USE THIS `flag` and `id` to update state or method call or 
    What ever you wanted too.
}
```

And inside Child component pass these two param

```
 this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData(VALUE_OF `flag`, Value of `id`);
```

**FOR EDIT WITH PARAMS**

replace your code of navigation with this line

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", {name: l.name, subtitle: l.subtitle, ordemFunc: this.handleOrdem.bind(this)})>
```

You have to `bind` method not to call with arrow function

So the problem is

```
ordemFunc: () => this.handleOrdem()
```

Replace this line with

```
ordemFunc: this.handleOrdem.bind(this)
```

Comment: Hey, this works, but how do I handle received data? I've declared a variable "param" on the constructor as: this.param = 'none', I show it in a Text, but when I update it with the params received by the function, it comes null, how come?

Comment: I don't really get it, I should do like: this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData(flag: 'Text', id: 10); or this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData('Text', 10); Either way, none seems to work

Comment: this.props.navigation.state.params.returnData('Text', 10);

Comment: When I console.log the received params it turns out to be 'undefined'

Comment: Using a global variable got it working, but its not optimal, how could I actually do it by params??

Comment: Check your code once may be you are making any mistakes while passing params or while using this params...because in my case it is working perfectlly.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the additional information on how I'm passing the params, can you check it out?

Comment: ordemFunc: () => this.handleOrdem()})     

 problem is here   replace it with 

ordemFunc:  this.handleOrdem.bind(this)})

Comment: Perfect, all working correctly, sorry for the trouble, it was a solution I was trying before your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this exact same issue and the problem is actually quite simple. We will utilise a callback for passing the params when we trigger goBack()

For example lets say I have two Views: ViewA and ViewB.
For which I will do as follows:

1. import useNavigation hook for setting up navigation.
2. When navigating to the next screen pass a callback ie: function with the       specified paramaters for the values you would like to pass back to ViewA.
3. In ViewB use the route prop to get access to the params. In here you will find your callback.
4. Use your callback and pass in the correct arguments to your callback.
5. Call the navigation.goBack() to return to ViewA
6. In ViewA you will now have access to your value in your callback.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { View, Button } from "react-native";
   import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

   const ViewA = () => {
     const navigation = useNavigation();
     return (
       <View>
         <Button
           onPress={() =>
             navigation.navigate("ViewB", {
               handleItem: (item) => console.log(item), // will log out "Your Item"
             })
           }
         />
       </View>
     );
   };

   const ViewB = ({ route }) => {
     const navigation = useNavigation;
     return (
       <View>
         <Button
           onPress={() => {
             route.params.handleItem("Your Item");
             navigation.goBack();
           }}
         />
       </View>
     );
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-navigation v2` you no need to use navigation.goBack() to go back to Main screen

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', { myParam: value })` will declaratively  handle the navigation back (with same transition) for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the data in the global state and call it again when you goBack

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log("its focus");
      //call the new data and update state here 
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
```