# React Native: Passing a toast message to navigated screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, toast

I have a button that redirect to other screen and also shows a toast message. i am using react-native-easy-toast.

```
  onPress={()=>{
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
    this.refs.toast.show('Message has been sent!',DURATION.LENGTH_LONG);                          
  }}/>
```

If I do this then it shows the toast and then redirect to other screen. But I want to make the toast appear to navigated screen after pressing the button. What should I do and how should I approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send props on navigation goBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960101/send-props-on-navigation-goback)

Comment: Not really, I am looking for a way to pass a function to another screen. lets say this toast, I will pass it to next screen and pop there. @axel

Comment: [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Comment: @ZeedTanue did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `setTimeout` for your case.
Like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.refs.toast.show('Message has been sent!',DURATION.LENGTH_LONG);
}, 500);
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze may i asked why sir ? cause i have try it in my project and it work fine.. the only different is I use the simple-toast instead of his libraty.

Comment: Because you should never rely on `setTimeout` this is an error prone approach. I'm certain there is something in react-native to solve exactly this scenario.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Oh. I get it. Thank you for that advise.